# Async data binding in Angular2 taking time even after data is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable

I am using Firebase in Angular2 to fetch an object.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  fireObj: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
     let id = params['id'];

      this.fireObj = this.af.database.object("/path/" + id);

      this.fireObj.subscribe(data => {
        if(data.$value !== null) {
          console.log(data);
        }else {
          console.log("failed");
        }
      });

     });
  }
}
```

And I am binding `fireObj` in the template:

```
<p>{{ (fireObj | async)?.title }}</p>
```

Everything works fine as expected, but sometimes console is logging `data` (say after 1 second) but dom/template is getting updated after 5-10 seconds.

Is there any particular reason for this behavior?

Comment: My only guess is that the async call is happening outside of ngZone, try looking into that

Comment: @SyntacticFructose thanks for your suggestion, I will look into it. But the behavior should remain consistent right? Sometimes, it is responding normally. I have also noticed that changing the `id` of path param is resulting in normal behavior but reloading the page (for the same id) few many times is creating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by explicitly calling `run()` method of `ngZone`.

```
this.fireObj.subscribe(data => {
    // some other code.
    this._ngZone.run(() => {});
});
```

I know this is not the best solution, but I have made sure that `_ngZone.run()` is called only once (that is during the first callback) as after that Angular is binding to it normally.

Thanks to @SyntacticFructose for guiding me in the correct direction.